# Sticky navbar creating white space

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am making a personal website and I am having issues with my sticky navbar. When the site loads the navbar is intended to go on top of section #home but it generates a white space for itself and it's supposed to take the background image of section #home/be on top of it and on top of every other section on the website (SEE PICTURE)

[image: 1]

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Setting Website Settings -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Mark6712</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Mark6712's personal website.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Mark6712, Programming, C, C++, Software, Personal">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark6712">

  <!-- Setting the Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/assets/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/assets/favicon/site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/assets/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Mark6712">
  <meta name="application-name" content="Mark6712">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/assets/favicon/mstile-144x144.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/assets/favicon/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#44444c">

  <!-- Importing CSS/JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/navbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/main.css">
  <script src="/assets/scripts/navbar.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a class="nav-logo" href="#">Mark6712</a>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <section id="home">
      <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>This is the home page.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
        <p>This is the about page.</p>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**navbar.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova&display=swap');
.navbar {
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: 1vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.50);
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-logo {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: .5rem;
    left: .7rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav-links {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.nav-links ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 8%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.50);
        backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.50);
    }

    .nav-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-links ul li a {
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }

    .nav-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

**main.css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}

html, body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

#home {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    color: aliceblue;
    background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**navbar.js**

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})

navbarLinks.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.remove('active')
})
```

Comment: have you tried setting `top: 0` to `.navbar` class?

Comment: Just play with your styles, remove every padding and margin, also it might be position sticky/relative issue

Comment: > have you tried setting top: 0 to .navbar class?
yes

Comment: @Alopwer nope, tried it, no success

Comment: line height issue?

Comment: @Alopwer the same issue + the page becomes even more broken

Comment: can you share it in codesandbox? I'll try to find the solution

Comment: @Alopwer okay, thank you! https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-html-css-js-sandbox-forked-cr804w

Comment: Just set top: 0, I've done it and everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using the float property and setting the width of the navbar to 100%.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%; /* new line */
  float: right; /* new line */
  clear: both; /* new line */
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

#home {
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(22, 29, 36);
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%; /* new line */
  float: right; /* new line */
  clear: both; /* new line */
}

.nav-logo {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  left: 0.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.nav-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 8%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="nav-logo" href="#">Mark6712</a>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
  <section id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>This is the home page.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>This is the about page.</p>
  </section>
</main>
```